# Access Denied when running .exe file with Jenkins

Tags: windows, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, exe

I have a windows server that is running Jenkins.

As part of my Jenkins pipeline, I am running an executable.

The link in the Jenkins file is:

```
bat 'DAIRunner.exe -vv param1 http://url.com param2'
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Access Denied
EROR: Script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone think why this might be? Is there a chmod equivalent I can do in Windows maybe?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the error is while trying to invoke the executable? Have you tried specifying the full path to executable and invoking (ie: `bat 'C:\path\to\DAIRunner.exe ...'` ? Also, try adding `set verbose on` on the first line of the step as well.

Answer (score 0):

[With Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-7.2), on the Jenkins Windows agent where the pipeline is executed, you can check the ACL associated with the file, or its parent folders.
Or simply check its Security properties, from a file explorer.

Then compare that with the account used by the Jenkins agent (you can add a `bat 'echo %USERNAME%'`).

That way, you can check if the Jenkins agent user has the right to access said file.

```
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-7.2
```

Comment: Hi VonC, how do I check 'the ACL associated with the file, or its parent folders'? 
If the user has the right to access the file, what would I see in the output ?

Comment: @PKen You would see which account has the right to access/execute the file. And you need to check the parent folders too. Keep in mind Jenkins might run with a system account, or another account, depending on how the agent has been set up.